# Named Parameters in SQuirreL SQL?

Tags: query, tools, parameter

Is it possible to set named-parameters in queries [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out, it's easy, you just add `:paramName` in your query and it automatically asks your for the parameters when you run the query.